# How to resolve a NullPointerException while using RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I am using two RecyclerViews in my app, one in the MainActivity and one in another activity. The one in the MainActivity works fine but the other has a NullPointerException and I don't know where the problem here is.

Here is a code snippet of the second RecyclerView, where the logcat says that there is a Null object reference. I used the same code as the first RecyclerView where everything works.

The error message says that there is a problem in this line: `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);`

and in this line
`initRecyclerViewFriendOverView();`

Here is where I implemented my second RecyclerView:

```
private void initRecyclerViewFriendOverView() {

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewFriendOverView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RecyclerViewAdapterFriendOverView adpater = new RecyclerViewAdapterFriendOverView(mNames, mImageUrls, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adpater);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_overview);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        init();
        initRecyclerViewFriendOverView();
        getImages();
    }
```

Here ist the XML where the second RecyclerView is used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewFreundesUebersicht"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Edit:**

The problem was that I called the RecyclerView before initializing it in the onCreate method.

Comment: The logcat report will give you the exact line where the code issues out. Please check it out or post it.

Comment: I wrote in the description where the Logical says is a problem but I don't know what to change there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Kaiser Post your xml from other activity

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide additional code or XML. Please don't post it in comments.

Comment: post error logcat

Comment: I edited the question with additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

You are including another xml file in your activity using `include` statement, findViewById() won't be able to find views from included layouts. Give an id to your `include` statement, find that included view first and then call findViewById () in that view:

In Activity layout file:

```
<include id="includedRecyclerLayout"
....
</include>
```

And in your code:

```
ConstraintLayout includedLayout = findViewById(R.id.inckudedRecyclerLayout);

RecyclerView recyclerview = includedLayout.findViewById(R.id.RECYCLER_VIEW_ID);
```

If it shows error at `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);` it means your **`recyclerView`** is null. Then you look at where you initialized it:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewFreundesUebersicht);
```

It can be null because of two reasons:

- You didn't add the RecyclerView to XML
- Your `R.id.recyclerViewFreundesUebersicht` is referring to a view from another xml

Check your XML and make sure your recyclerview was added to XML and the id you are using here is same as the one used in activity.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added a RecyclerView to the XML otherwise it would display a different error and also the R.id is referring to the right view

Comment: @Kaiser can you post the layout file?

Comment: I edited my question with additional information, I hope you can find a solution with these information, I appreciate your assistance

Comment: @Kaiser what are the names of layout files of both activities?

Comment: The first is app_bar_main.xml with the RecyclerView id recyclerViewAktuelleSpiele and the second is freundesUebersicht.xml with the RecyclerView id recyclerViewFreundesUebersicht

Comment: @Kaiser check your `setContentView()` and see if you provided the right layout id

Comment: @Kaiser found your problem, are you including a separate layout file in your xml?

Comment: Ok I figured it out, I had the RecyclerView in the wrong Java class

Answer (score 1):

Initialize LinearLayoutManager like this

```
  LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```